# Regex with strings contaning url and text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace a string containing a url and text to just the url. I'm doing this:

```
const url = 'hello https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test'
  
const urlreg = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;

url.replace(urlreg,(url)=> {
    return url
  })
```

When doing this it will return the text, anyway to remove the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be *possible* to match and remove the text, it'd make more sense to match and construct a new string from just the URLs - not with `.replace`, but with `.match`:

```js
const url = 'hello https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test';
const urlreg = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;
const stringWithOnlyURLS = url.match(urlreg).join(' ');
console.log(stringWithOnlyURLS);
```

If there might not be any URLs, then alternate with the empty array to avoid problems with `null` results:

```
const stringWithOnlyURLS = (url.match(urlreg) || []).join(' ');
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, would there be a way to therefore also take the text that isn't url?

Comment: Match URLs with the regular expression and replace with the empty string, and you'll get the text without any URLs